# Energy-Momentum Tensor with mixed indices

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, notation, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I know that $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the Energy-Momentum Tensor and $T=g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$, but does anyone know what $T^{\nu}_{\mu}$ is and how its calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T_\mu^\nu = T_{\mu\sigma}g^{\sigma\nu}$